# How can I get my python code to be more efficient?

Tags: python, processing-efficiency

I want to improve the efficiency of my Python code, while keeping the run time in the limit (3 seconds). How can I improve my code here?

**This is the given problem**: *Dan has a list of problems. The difficulties of these problems are stored in a list of integers a. The i-th problem’s difficulty is represented by a[i].

You must select at least two problems from the list. Since there are many possible subsets, you may consider only sublists (definition follows).

You want to pick problems that don’t vary too much in difficulty. What is the smallest difference between the difficulties of the most difficult selected problem and the least difficult selected problem you can achieve by selecting a sublist of length at least 2 of the original list of problems?

**Definition**: A sublist of a list a is a segment of the list.

**Input**
The list a, separated by single spaces.

**Output**
The smallest difference in difficulties you can achieve.

**Constraints**
2 <= len(a) <= 500000
1 <= a[i] <= 10**9

Time Limit: 3 seconds

**Sample Input 1**
10 6 9 1

**Sample Output 1**
3

**My code:**

```
import time # import time module
arr = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))

st = time.time()
diff = 10**9
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    max_ele = min_ele = arr[i]
    for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
        max_ele = max(max_ele, arr[j])
        min_ele = min(min_ele, arr[j])
        if max_ele - min_ele <= diff:
            diff = max_ele - min_ele
    
print(diff)
# end = time.time() - st
#print(end)
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem statement but don’t you just need the minimum of two consecutive numbers? So something like `min([abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(arr[1:],arr[:-1])])`?

Comment: I meant ‘minimum difference’

Comment: Yes I believe so, was hoping I can get some help with making my current code more efficient, and fit the constraints.

Comment: If the minimum difference of consecutive elements is what you need, my snippet there should be all it takes after defining the array. It’s linear in time, so it should be really fast.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it lacks clarity on what you need. You mentioned "more efficient" but only mentioned an upper bound. Does your code currently take longer than 3 seconds to run? Are you trying to make it run faster? Or are you trying to reduce the number of lines of code? Some other metric of "more efficient"?

Comment: Damn, that hurt. Although I do partially agree with your point, yes I should've been more clear on the objective of my question. Do please take into account that I am new to this platform, a simple comment without voting to diminish my question could have worked as well, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the sublists or segments as sliding windows over the array. Because the minimum length is two, the question is equivalent to asking for the minimum difference in a sublist of **exactly** two, ie consecutive elements. In python you can do this with a list, or better generator, comprehension

```
diff=min((abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(arr[:-1],arr[1:])))
```

As a loop

```
diff=10**9
for a,b in zip(arr[:-1],arr[1:]):
    diff=min(diff,abs(a-b))
return diff
```

Comment: Would I implement this in my current code above? and would it then work

Comment: Your current code does too much. You are checking for each segment of every possible length, plus your inner loop recomputes the same minima and maxima over and over. You can replace them with a single loop. You should read up on sliding windows, and think about how you would solve the same problem if the minimal sublist length was bigger than two.